# Shell script with password in Jenkins

Tags: shell, jenkins, passwords

I have created a Jenkins job which executes a shell script. "Unsafe" people can open it and start the job. The job executes a db tool in shell which requires the db password. 
The Jenkins instance is run on a computer which can be accessed by "unsafe" people. The job is delegated to a slave which is accessed by "safe" people.

This is a parameterized build, has one parameter: password as Password Parameter.

For the sake of brevity the relevant part of the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash +x
dban -u username -p ${password}
```

It runs fine and fails fine if the password is not correct. Echoing the command invoked is disabled by +x as the first line says.

Is this that simple? What else should I consider for safety reasons?

Comment: I believe your jobs is safe but if you want more precautio see [here](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Job+Restrictions+Plugin) how to disable manual build, this way you can start the build only as delegate job.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want people to run the build and not have to pass in the parameter of the password?  If so you should checkout setting up a credential for it.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/203802500-Injecting-Secrets-into-Jenkins-Build-Jobs

https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/user.adoc